# Compute the following integral without using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to compute the following integral.
$\int_{\partial R_r}\frac{dz}{(z-2)^2}$ where $R_r$ is the following set:

$R_r= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} :  |Rez| \leq r \space and \space |Imz|\leq 1\}$ for $r>2$ .

But I can not use the residue theorem.

I thought abut using the equality $a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial B_r(2)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-2)^2}d\zeta = \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(2)$ with $f(z)=1$ so the integral would be zero but I dont know if it works.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{\mathrm d z}{(z-2)^2}= \mathrm d \left( \frac{-1}{z-2} \right).$$

Comment: There is no "$r$" in your definition of $R_r$. so claiming the definition is for $r > 2$ is meaningless.

Comment: It was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If $r > 2$ then $\partial R_r$ is homologous to $\alpha: [0,2\pi]\rightarrow U : t \rightarrow 2+e^{it}$

with $U = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{2\}$

So $\int_{\partial R_r} \frac{dz}{z-2} = \int_{\alpha} \frac{dz}{z-2} = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dz}{(2+e^{it}-2)^2}ie^{it}dt = i \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{e^{it}}=0$